# What is the password for a git push to a repo on the same machine,different user?

Tags: git, ssh

I have decided to make the web projects in the web root directory into git repositories, it just seems logical.

I initialized the repository using, I was the root user at the time, and it gave me a message about configuring name and email which I ignored:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "My project Name"
git remote add origin git@myserver.com:my_project.git
```

Then:

Using the git user, as the bare (central) repositories are kept on the same server I setup the bare repo with the git user:

```
git init --bare my_project.git
```

Then using the root user I wanted to push the repo to the bare repo created so I used:

```
git push -u origin master
```

However it `asks for a password` and I am unsure which one, it is not the root password of the system, Would it be the `ssh passphrase` of the root user or the password for the git user?

Do I need to add the root user to authorized_keys of the git user's `.ssh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the ssh password of the user `git` on server `myserver.com`

Answer (score 0):

Git is trying to connect to the remote server as the `git` user, and is failing the key authentication, thus falling back to password authentication (which in most cases will never work since, usually, the git user has no auth credentials).

To resolve, add your SSH public key to the `git` user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote server.